# magento admin tab with product grid. grid serializer error

Tags: magento-1.9, grid-serlization

**instagrampro.xml file code is**

```
<adminhtml_instagrampro_related>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
            <block type="instagrampro/adminhtml_instagrampro_edit_tab_related" name="adminhtml.pinstagram.related"/>
            <block type="adminhtml/widget_grid_serializer" name="related_grid_serializer">
                <reference name="related_grid_serializer">
                    <action method="initSerializerBlock">
                        <grid_block_name>adminhtml.pinstagram.related</grid_block_name>
                        <data_callback>getSelectedProduct</data_callback>
                        <hidden_input_name>links[related]</hidden_input_name>
                        <reload_param_name>products_related</reload_param_name>
                    </action>
                    <action method="addColumnInputName">
                        <input_name>position</input_name>
                    </action>
                </reference>
            </block>
        </block>
</adminhtml_instagrampro_related>

<adminhtml_instagrampro_relatedgrid>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
        <block type="instagrampro/adminhtml_instagrampro_edit_tab_related" name="adminhtml.pinstagram.related"/>
    </block>
</adminhtml_instagrampro_relatedgrid>
```

**grid.php file is**

```
<?php

/**
 * Magento Instagrampro extension
 *
 * @category   Magecomp
 * @package    Magecomp_Instagrampro
 * @author     Magecomp
 */

class Magecomp_Instagrampro_Block_Adminhtml_Instagrampro_Edit_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs
{
    public function __construct()
     {
          parent::__construct();
          $this->setId('instagrampro_tabs');
          $this->setDestElementId('edit_form');
          $this->setTitle('Image Configuration');
      }
      protected function _beforeToHtml()
      {
          $this->addTab('form_section', array(
                   'label' => 'Image Information',
                   'title' => 'Image Information',
                   'content' => $this->getLayout()
     ->createBlock('instagrampro/adminhtml_instagrampro_edit_tab_form')
     ->toHtml()
         ));

        $this->addTab('related', array(
                'label'     => 'Related Products',
                'url'       => $this->getUrl('*/*/related', array('_current' => true)),
                'class'     => 'ajax',
            ));




         return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }
}

?>
```

**related.php is**

```
<?php
class Magecomp_Instagrampro_Block_Adminhtml_Instagrampro_Edit_Tab_Related extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    /**
     * Set grid params
     *
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('related_product_grid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
        $this->setDefaultFilter(array('in_products' => 1));
    }

    /**
     * Retirve currently edited product model
     *
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
     */
    protected function _getProduct()
    {
        if(!Mage::registry('instagrampro_data')){
            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
            $model = Mage::getModel('pinstagram/pinstagram');
             $model->load($id);
            Mage::register('instagrampro_data', $model);
        }

        return Mage::registry('instagrampro_data');

    }

    /**
     * Add filter
     *
     * @param object $column
     * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Related
     */
    protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
    {
        // Set custom filter for in product flag
        if ($column->getId() == 'in_products') {
            $productIds = $this->_getSelectedProducts();
            if (empty($productIds)) {
                $productIds = 0;
            }

            if ($column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
                $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds));
            } else {
                if($productIds) {
                    $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('nin' => $productIds));
                }
            }
        } else {
            parent::_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare collection
     *
     * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_link')->useRelatedLinks()
            ->getProductCollection()
            //->setProduct($this->_getProduct())
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        if ($this->isReadonly()) {
            $productIds = $this->_getSelectedProducts();
            if (empty($productIds)) {
                $productIds = array(0);
            }
            $collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds));
        }

        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Checks when this block is readonly
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isReadonly()
    {

        return false;// $this->_getProduct()->getReadonly();
    }

    /**
     * Add columns to grid
     *
     * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {

        if (!$this->isReadonly()) {
            $this->addColumn('in_products', array(
                'header_css_class'  => 'a-center',
                'type'              => 'checkbox',
                'name'              => 'in_products',
                'values'            => $this->_getSelectedProducts(),
                'align'             => 'center',
                'index'             => 'entity_id'
            ));
        }

        $this->addColumn('entity_id_product', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('ID'),
            'sortable'  => true,
            'width'     => 60,
            'index'     => 'entity_id'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('name_product', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Name'),
            'index'     => 'name'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('type_product', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Type'),
            'width'     => 100,
            'index'     => 'type_id',
            'type'      => 'options',
            'options'   => Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_type')->getOptionArray(),
        ));

        $sets = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_set_collection')
            ->setEntityTypeFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getTypeId())
            ->load()
            ->toOptionHash();

        $this->addColumn('set_name_product', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Attrib. Set Name'),
            'width'     => 130,
            'index'     => 'attribute_set_id',
            'type'      => 'options',
            'options'   => $sets,
        ));

        $this->addColumn('product_status_product', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Status'),
            'width'     => 90,
            'index'     => 'status',
            'type'      => 'options',
            'options'   => Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->getOptionArray(),
        ));

        $this->addColumn('visibility_product', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Visibility'),
            'width'     => 90,
            'index'     => 'visibility',
            'type'      => 'options',
            'options'   => Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getOptionArray(),
        ));

        $this->addColumn('sku_product', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('SKU'),
            'width'     => 80,
            'index'     => 'sku'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('price_product', array(
            'header'        => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Price'),
            'type'          => 'currency',
            'currency_code' => (string) Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Directory_Model_Currency::XML_PATH_CURRENCY_BASE),
            'index'         => 'price'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('position', array(
            'header'            => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Position'),
            'name'              => 'position',
            'type'              => 'number',
            'validate_class'    => 'validate-number',
            'index'             => 'position',
            'width'             => 60,
            'editable'          => true,
            //'edit_only'         => !$this->_getProduct()->getId()
        ));

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    /**
     * Rerieve grid URL
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getData('grid_url')
            ? $this->getData('grid_url')
            : $this->getUrl('*/*/relatedGrid', array('_current' => true));
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve selected related products
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _getSelectedProducts()
    {
        $products = $this->getProductsRelated();

        if (!is_array($products)) {
            $products = array_keys($this->getSelectedRelatedProducts());
        }
        return $products;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve related products
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getSelectedRelatedProducts()
    {
        $products = array();


        if(!Mage::registry("news_related_data")){

            $colRelated = $this->getRelatedProducts();
            Mage::register("news_related_data", $colRelated);
        }

        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        //if(count(Mage::registry("news_related_data"))> 0)
        foreach (Mage::registry("news_related_data") as $product) {
            $products[$product->getEntityId()] = array('position' => $product->getPosition());
        }

    // var_dump($products);die;
        return $products;
    }

    public function getRelatedProducts(){
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $collection = Mage::getModel('instagrampro/instagramproimage')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('ins_id', $id)
                    ->load()
                    ;           
        return $collection;
    }


}
```

**in controller action**

```
public function relatedAction()
        {
            $this->loadLayout();
```

```
         /**
         * 68 line in controller
         *
         */
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('adminhtml.pinstagram.related')
                    ->setProductsRelated($this->getRequest()->getPost('id', null))
                   ;
```

```
            $this->renderLayout();

        }

        /**
         * Get related products grid
         */
        public function relatedGridAction()
        {
            $this->_initPinstagram();
            $this->loadLayout();
            $this->getLayout()->getBlock('adminhtml.pinstagram.related')
                ->setProductsRelated($this->getRequest()->getPost('id', null));
            $this->renderLayout();
        }
```

error in edit is

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setProductsRelated() on
>   boolean in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\instagram\app\code\local\Magecomp\Instagrampro\controllers\Adminhtml\ProindexController.php
>   on line 68

Comment: Post your code of file "instagram\app\code\local\Magecomp\Instagrampro\controllers\Adminhtml\ProindexController.php"

Comment: i add controller code at last you check

Comment: Put comment in front of line number 68 so the we get where the issue is

Comment: in controller action you find setProductsRelated

Comment: you just check i add commentt

Comment: In error you showing 'setSelectedCustomers()', is it setProductsRelated() ?

Comment: ya that is my mistack i edit my question you just check

Comment: @jigs parmar  can you help me to integrating intagram api to magento

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to add reference name

```
<adminhtml_instagrampro_related>
    <reference name="content">
    <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
        <block type="instagrampro/adminhtml_instagrampro_edit_tab_related" name="adminhtml.pinstagram.related"/>
        <block type="adminhtml/widget_grid_serializer" name="related_grid_serializer">
            <reference name="related_grid_serializer">
                <action method="initSerializerBlock">
                    <grid_block_name>adminhtml.pinstagram.related</grid_block_name>
                    <data_callback>getSelectedProduct</data_callback>
                    <hidden_input_name>links[related]</hidden_input_name>
                    <reload_param_name>products_related</reload_param_name>
                </action>
                <action method="addColumnInputName">
                    <input_name>position</input_name>
                </action>
            </reference>
        </block>
    </block>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_instagrampro_related>

<adminhtml_instagrampro_relatedgrid>
<reference name="content">
    <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
    <block type="instagrampro/adminhtml_instagrampro_edit_tab_related" name="adminhtml.pinstagram.related"/>
    </block>
</reference>
</adminhtml_instagrampro_relatedgrid>
```

Comment: no any effact it give me same error

Comment: @jigs parmar : have you done this as I am also getting same error.

Comment: ya i solve this

Comment: can you provide me solution for this